# Why is time of the last activity not shown in some questions?

Tags: support, timestamps

I have noticed that in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738707/prerequisites-for-differential-galois-theory) on the right the time of the last activity is not shown. (Usually you have there 3 entries: asked, viewed - with number of views, active.)

When you view [recently active questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-algebra?sort=active) in the given tag, the last activity is shown as Nov 9. (Which is when a bounty was placed on this question.)

Is this a bug? Or is this intentional?

I suppose that this can change when there is some new activity in the question. So here are two snapshots from Wayback Machine:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20141201085934/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738707/prerequisites-for-differential-galois-theory
- http://web.archive.org/web/20141201090137/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-algebra?sort=active

And also a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Note that answering a question will count as an "activity" on a question (and thus change the "last activity time", though it is still says  "modified"), but does not count as an "action" on the question post itself. There is probably something similar happening with bounties.

Comment: According to this post, last activity is only shown if a post has answer. Meta.SE: [Why is there no last activity message?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211073/why-is-there-no-last-activity-message). So it does not matter, whether a post was edited or had a bounty.

Comment: Basically the problem was on my side - I simply should have noticed that there are *many questions* where *last active* is not shown and that they are usually questions with no answer. (Such as this one was, just a few minutes ago.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133283/),

> The "active" stat in the sidebar is only displayed for questions that have answers.

For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390329/) has been edited but there is no "active" timestamp in the sidebar.

I think the reason for the "having answers" restriction is that the "active" timestamp is a link (to the question URL with `?lastactivity` appended). Its intended use is for people to be able to jump to the most recent answer posted to the question. If there are no answers, there is nowhere to jump to, so the link is useless. (Even though the timestamp might be of some use on its own.)

The link is still useless when the most recent activity on an answered question is an edit to the question, like [in this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244086/). But it's shown anyway.